# What is the cause for the MySQL error FUNCTION doesn't exist? It happens randomly. The server has a high number of databases on it like 900

Tags: mysql

It is a web application connecting to a MySQL 5.6 server in Amazon. The application using PHP code or Java gets randomly the error FUNCTION getSetting does not exist. It is basically doing a query like `select getSetting('a_setting_name');` or while used from the stored procedures.

In order to avoid the error some stored procedures were changed to not using the function and get the value by doing a raw select to the table. Also many not used databases were deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is defined in a different database than the one you've selected as the default, you need to qualify the function name with the database name, just as you would if you wanted to access a table or view in a different DB.

```
SELECT otherDB.getSetting('a_setting_name');
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar. It is in the same database and it doesn't need to be qualified. It works fine for many times then it fails randomly. Our first assumption was the high number of databases in the same server like 900 could be taking too much time for the engine to find the function in the information_schema.

Comment: Nope. If I had another idea it would be in my answer.

Comment: I found from other comments an issue related to the function creation script that should not have an space between the function name and the parenthesis. 
```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `getSettingValue` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `getSettingValue` (...)
```

Comment: I've seen that problem when *using* built-in functions; `SUM (column)` gets an error, but `SUM(column)` works. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/function-resolution.html. But it doesn't affect user-defined functions.

Comment: Yes, I have verified that too.